# Button Event on a Widget Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Ok so I've tried almost everything that comes to my mind but this button on my widget doesn't responds at all when touched. I want to open another class and associated xml when the button is clicked but the event does not responds..
following is my onUpdate() code

```
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
   final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

      Intent intent = new Intent(context, Launch.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);



      RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);
      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);


    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
  }
```

}

```
<receiver
android:name="com.example.widgetexample.ExampleAppWidgetProvider"
android:label="8-bit cloud widget 1" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget1_inf" />
</receiver>
```

The application runs successfully after the error that it stopped un expectedly.widget's adds to the screen but the button doesnt works..p.s Im new to android.Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are missing to start intent like `startActivity(intent);` I don't know whether this is correct or not.

Comment: No not in the case of widget..as far as i know Pendingintent doest it all for you..I've seen a couple of examples as well